# Install Firefox v22 and Firefox Nightly without interference

Tags: 13.04, firefox, mozilla

I am going to be a tester for Mozilla. I want to install Firefox Nightly and still keep my stable Firefox. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://www.webupd8.org/2011/05/install-firefox-nightly-from-ubuntu-ppa.html that should explain everything to know about installing firefox nightly(trunk) alongside Regualar without messing your stuff up, in ubuntu. hope this helps :)

Comment: no problem :) glad i could help

Comment: Is there anything similar for Aurora?

Answer (score 2):

For Aurora, just simply paste this into terminal,

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-mozilla-daily/firefox-aurora
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install firefox
```

NOTE: You’ll notice that this package name is the same as it is in the official repository. This means that you can’t have both installed at the same time. You can ‘pin’ a package to a given source and version, allowing you to install a specific version from a specific source. But, as long as the package names are the same, they can’t be installed concurrently. You’ll have to compile and execute one version from the source if you want to do this.

Sorry, there is no other way to install Aurora other than doing it over the Stable

Comment: I will ask the developers of that PPA if they can tweak the package to allow coexistent installs.

Comment: Sounds good, if you need anymore help, just comment and i'll try to help the best i can.